Is there a way to decrease counter in a For Each loop?
I have the following source csv (wbSource):



ID
Value




125
A


145
A


173
A


201
A


203
A


650
B


888
B



I want to use VBA to copy all rows with Value = A to a table "Principal" in another workbook ("Target.xlsb"), with the exception of any rows that might already be there. The rows in the destination table cannot be changed for several reasons, mainly because they may have new information not present in the source csv.
To acomplish this, I have a function that checks if the IDs with Value = A already exist in the Principal table. If yes, the loop deletes the row in the sorce csv.
The goal would be that, after running this function, I would filter my source csv by "A" Value and copy all visible rows to my target table.
However, by doing this, it skips one row in the following iteration.
This is the function I created (with the help of IA), and it works perfectly if it weren't for the row skipping each time a row is deleted.
Function CheckAndDeleteRows() As String
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim tblPrincipal As ListObject
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngPrincipal As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim found As Range

    ' Open the workbooks
    Set wbSource = Workbooks("Source.csv")
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks("Target.xlsb")

' Set the worksheet in Source workbook and the table in Target workbook
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(1)
    Set tblPrincipal = wbTarget.Sheets(1).ListObjects("Principal")

    ' Set the ranges to check
    Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("B2:B" & wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rngPrincipal = tblPrincipal.DataBodyRange.Columns(1)

    ' Loop through each cell in column B of Source workbook
    For Each cell In rngSource
        If cell.Value = "A" Then
            ' Check if the value is in the Principal table of Target workbook
            Set found = rngPrincipal.Find(cell.EntireRow.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not found Is Nothing Then
                ' Delete the row in Source workbook
                cell.EntireRow.Delete

               ' THIS IS WHERE I'D LIKE TO DECREASE THE COUNTER BY ONE'

            End If
        End If
    Next cell

End Function

The optimum solution would be able to decrease the counter after cell.EntireRow.Delete, something along the lines of cell = cell - 1, but this method doesn't allow that.
Is there any other way to decrease the "For Each cell" counter by 1 every time the loop deletes a row in the source csv?


Looping in reverse order is an approach for deleting rows to avoid issues with cells shifting after deletion.
Change For Each to For loop
cell.EntireRow.Value : EntireRow is useless

    Dim lastRow As Long, iRow As Long
    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For iRow = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        Set cell = wsSource.Cells(iRow, "B")
        If cell.Value = "A" Then
            Set found = rngPrincipal.Find(cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not found Is Nothing Then
                cell.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next cell



A better approach is to delete all rows after looping. You don't need to worry about the looping order and cells shifting.

    Dim lastRow As Long, iRow As Long, delRng As Range
    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For iRow = 2 To lastRow
        Set cell = wsSource.Cells(iRow, "B")
        If cell.Value = "A" Then
            Set found = rngPrincipal.Find(cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not found Is Nothing Then
                If Not delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = Union(delRng, cell)
                Else
                    Set delRng = cell
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.EntireRow.Delete


A VBA Lookup: Delete Rows

Instead of looping through cells, you can improve efficiency by looping through the elements of an array (sfData).
Instead of using the Find method, you can improve efficiency by using Application.Match which can be applied to the whole range resulting in an array (trIndices) of matching row indices and error values.

Sub CheckAndDeleteRows()
    
    ' Source
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks("Source.csv")
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(1) ' the one and only
    Dim slrg As Range, sfData() As Variant
    With sws.Range("B2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        Set slrg = .EntireRow.Columns("A") ' lookup
        sfData = .Value ' filter
    End With
    
    ' Target
    Dim twb As Workbook: Set twb = Workbooks("Target.xlsb")
    ' If 'Target.xlsb' is the name of the workbook containing this code,
    ' use the following instead:
    'Dim twb As Workbook: Set twb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = twb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim tlo As ListObject: Set tlo = tws.ListObjects("Principal")
    Dim tlrg As Range: Set tlrg = tlo.DataBodyRange.Columns(1) ' lookup
    Dim trIndices() As Variant: trIndices = Application.Match(slrg, tlrg, 0)

    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim surg As Range, sr As Long
    
    ' Loop.
    For sr = 1 To UBound(sfData, 1)
        If StrComp(CStr(sfData(sr, 1)), "A", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            If IsNumeric(trIndices(sr, 1)) Then
                If surg Is Nothing Then
                    Set surg = slrg.Cells(sr)
                Else
                    Set surg = Union(surg, slrg.Cells(sr))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sr

    ' Delete in one go.
    If Not surg Is Nothing Then
        surg.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
        MsgBox "Existing records deleted.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No matching records found!", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub

